# How to validate user inputs obtained from options of letters (i.e. without keyboard)?

Tags: java, android

I am developing a questions and answers game that asks questions to users and for answer instead of keyboard different letters are provided and the user has to select the correct letters to form a word i.e. the answer. The combination of letters should match the correct answer...if it does not an error should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Store the selected letters into a string and use `equals` to check if it matches the correct answer.

```
String selectedLetters = "abc";
String answer = "abc";

if(selectedLetters.equals(answer)) {
    // Correct answer
} else {
    // Incorrect answer
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply...I actually was going to use the string resource for the validation but how do I define that the combination of letters (separately tapped by the user) IS actually the "selectedLetters". The input will be given by tapping one button (letter) at a time...and even if one letter is incorrect then it should display an error. The game and interface is similar to this one: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xsCSE.jpg

Comment: Build the string when each button is pressed. Eg. on click selectedLetters = selectedLetters + "[letter pressed]". Add the above if statement into a method and call that method every time a button is pressed to continually validate the answer

Comment: If I've answered your question please upvote and mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `String` using:

```
String selectedLetters = "";
selectedLetters.append('a'); // This adds the letter "a" to the string
```

And check if the given answer is correct when the strings are the same length.

```
if (selectedLetters.length() == answer.length) {
    if(selectedLetters.equals(answer)) {
        // Correct answer
    } else {
        // Incorrect answer
    }
}
```